# Bedeutung des »auch« in »wenn sie sich auch vom Schloß nicht entfernte«

Tags: meaning-in-context

In dieser Frage geht es um »auch« im folgenden Auszug aus *Das Schloß* von Kafka, wie betont:

> So ging er wieder vorwärts, aber es war ein langer Weg. Die Straße nämlich, die Hauptstraße des Dorfes, führte nicht zum Schloßberg, sie führte nur nahe heran, dann aber, wie absichtlich, bog sie ab, und **wenn** sie sich **auch** vom Schloß nicht entfernte, so kam sie ihm doch **auch** nicht näher.

**FRAGEN**

1. Geht das erste Vorkommen des Wortes »auch« mit »wenn« (wie betont) zusammen, um »although« oder »even though« zu bedeuten?
2. Wenn ja zu 1, kann man den Satz wie »auch wenn. . .« umformulieren?
3. Wenn nein zu 1, was bedeutet das erste »auch«?  Geht es zum Beispiel irgendwie mit dem zweiten »auch« zusammen, um »neither... neither...« zu bedeuten?

**HINTERGRUND**

Ich glaube, im ersten Fall bedeutet der Satz:

> and **even** though it did not recede from the castle, it did not go nearer to it **either**

--in welchem die Wörter, die den beiden »auch« entsprechen, betont sind.

Comment: You are perfectly correct with 1, 2 and with your translation.

Comment: @user1583209: It's not me, but answering a question by commenting demotivates those who want to give a »real« answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wenn* in Verbindung mit *auch* bedeutet soviel wie *obwohl*

Duden sagt dazu

> obwohl, obgleich
> Grammatik
> konzessiv in Verbindung mit »auch«, »schon« u. a.
>
> *wenn es auch anstrengend war, Spaß hat es doch gemacht*
>
> *es war nötig, wenn es ihm auch/auch wenn es ihm schwerfiel*

So, your assumptions (1), and (2) and your translation are correct, and (3) is a clear no.

With regards to (3): "Wenn auch...nicht" and "Weder ... noch" don't fit into the same sentence. If you want to express the same fact using "Weder...noch", you'd use some form like

> ...und entfernte sich weder vom Schloß, noch kam sie ihm näher.

which is grammatically correct, but sounds truly non-poetic to me compared to the original.